# How to install Python packages from Windows command line?

Tags: python, windows, command-line

I have a script that I wrote in Google Collab, and I'm installing the Geopandas, pandas, and descartes packages using !pip install [package] at the top of the script. However, when I run this script from the command line (I open the Terminal in Anaconda), I get a syntax error.

Comment: Can you write console output here?

Comment: What error?  What kind of script?

Comment: As a refresher, please read [ask]. We can only help you with errors that you actually show to us, and with problems that you [enable us to reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, you should make sure that your question title reflects the question you are actually asking. If you successfully installed the package and have a problem when you try to *run* it, then don't ask "how do I install the package?".

Comment: My script was written in Google Colab, I have the lines "!pip install geopandas" "!pip install pandas" "!pip install descartes" at the top, before defining the function I am creating. When I run the script from the command line I get the error, "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Therefore, the package is not being installed, because when I edit the script to just have "import geopandas" I get the error "No module named 'geopandas'"

Comment: I run the command by changing the directory to where my script is located and then typing "python script.py" But since the script has these !pip install at the top, the script won't run from the command line. I am not sure what the proper syntax is for the script, as when I run it inside of Google colab, there are no issues.

Comment: My script is quite long, but to summarize it's a script that reads longitude and latitude from a csv, and then plots them on a map.

Comment: In a `.py` script: use `import os` an then `os.system('pip install pandas')` etc. A leading _Exclamation Mark_  gives no sense for me…

Answer (score 0):

In normal Python, packages are installed by typing:

```bash
pip install <pkg_name>
```

into either PowerShell, Command Prompt or any other shells you have. Pure Python does not support installation via the code script

However, you could in theory write code that runs the shell commands to install the packages, something like the following:

```py
import subprocess

package_names = ['geopandas', 'pandas', 'descartes']

for pkg in package_names:
    try:
        process = subprocess.run(
            ['python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', pkg], 
            shell=True, check=True, text=True, 
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE
        )
        print(process)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print(e.returncode, e.stderr, e.output)
```

But as you can see, it isn't the simplest code any is extremely bad practise as it does not take into account any environments or cleanliness of the package installations. It is better to create a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) in your project folder and install the dependencies there

```bash
cd %userprofile%\path\to\project\folder
py -m venv .\project-env
.\project-env\scripts\activate.bat
pip install geopandas pandas descartes
pip freeze > .\requirements.txt
```

The above (in Windows Command Prompt, aka `cmd.exe`) will create a virtual environment, which means that all packages are isolated for that project, which will ensure there are no dependency conflicts, then activate the venv. It will then install the packages and write a requirements file that you can ship with your code

I hope this helps, good luck :D